# If $\varepsilon$ is a $n$-th root of unity, then it is a $d$-th primitive root of unity for some $d | n$, in a special case.

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, with $p = Char F$ a natural prime number and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p | n$. Let $\varepsilon$ be a root of $X^n - 1$. How can I see that there exists $d \in \mathbb{N}$, with $d | n$, such that $\varepsilon$ generates the group of $d$-th roots of unity?

Comment: I don't see where $n$ enters the picture.

Comment: Do you mean $n|d$ instead of $d|n$? Otherwise consider $p=2$, $n=6$, $d=3$. In $F=GF(2)$, we have $(X-1)^3=X^3+X^2+X+1\neq X^3+1=X^3-1$.

Comment: Thank you by your example. I have realized that my last statement was false, but I have just rewritten my question.

Comment: Let $d$ be the order of $\varepsilon$.